# Java primitive type variable storage

Tags: java, reference, primitive-types

I understand object variables store references (mem address) and primitive variable types store values but doesnt a primitive still need a mem addr to locate the value? Therefore does a primitive type variable actually store a ref (mem addr) to the value?

ie int num = 10; //num is the location of the 10 in memory?

Comment: To the extent that any variable must have a place in memory to store its value, yes.

Comment: For more information, you may want to look into how java uses the stack and the heap: https://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> ie int num = 10; //num is the location of the 10 in memory?
> ```

It's in stack, actually.

At least, local variables and parameters are. So, in:

```
public void foo() {
   int x = 10;
   System.out.println(x);
   int y = 20;
   System.out.println(y);
}
```

What's going to happen (and you compile the above, then run `javap -c` to check the byte code and follow along), is that javac compiles this down to bytecode that looks like:

```
STARTMETHOD foo SLOTS=1
LOADC 0, 10 # load constant value '10' into the first slot (slot 0)
PUSH # Push this on the stack.
INVOKESTATIC java/lang/System println(int)
LOADC 0, 20 # load constant value '20' into... the first slot!
PUSH
INVOKESTATIC java/lang/System println(int)
```

NB: This is highly oversimplified; System.out.println is actually a GETFIELD and then an interface invoke on the result, and many more such simplifications. But the bits relevant to stacks and slots represent how it works.

You see some interesting things here. Notably, that a local variable doesn't match 1-to-1 to a memory location. Javac realizes that you never use x when you make that y, so it just re-uses the same slot.

That 'slot' thing is declared **on the stack**. The stack is memory, but it's continuously being reused. The stack is a tiny bit of memory (think 1MB or so), and everytime you call a method, the place you came from, and all the state it has (the local vars and such) exist there, and all the new state (the local vars of the new method, so those slots for example) are put 'on top'. Then when you return from a method, that 'pointer pointing at the top of the stack' is right back to where it was, so the next method you invoke immediately overwrites this stuff.

So, is `num` a 'memory address'? Not really, because the address is literally '0' (the first slot). That doesn't translate to 'the 0th item on our stack'. It translates to 'the top of the stack as it was when this method was entered', bit of a stretch to call that a 'memory location'.

This variable, in any case, does not exist on the heap *at all* - the stack is separate from the heap.

For fields, it's different. Given:

```
class Foo {
   int num = 10;
   Object o = new Object();
}
```

this is *completely* different. Instances of Foo are represented by a bunch of memory on-heap. Specifically, some bytes to register that this is a Foo instance, then some bytes to store '10' (literally, 0x00 00 00 10 shows up in memory, possibly 0x10 00 00 00 depending on the endianness of things - you would find this if you coredump the process memory space), then some bytes to store a 'ref' to that object o.

References to that field are not stored as a memory address, ever. It's stored as a 'ref' to this Foo instance, and the VM translates 'get me the value of the `num` field as 'that's at the 10th offset relative to where the instance lives'.

If you want to call that a memory address, be my guest. But what possible point is there to decreeing it so?

a 'ref' is like a pointer, except it is usually not directly a memory address, but some number the JVM can use to determine the memory address. Generally objects are aligned on 8-byte boundaries, so on some VMs, this actually stores an 8th of the targeted memory address, or it's a mem address relative to something, or it's merely a key that is then looked up later. It depends on the VM and GC implementation and there is zero reason to know about this stuff, you can't observe any of this from within java code.

Comment: As I wrote my question, it dawned on me that primitives must be stored on the Stack (whereas Objects are on the Heap). If primitives are on the Stack, then how does this work?
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

System.out.println(a);

b would be on the top of the Stack so to access a, does Java shuffle a to the top of the Stack to access it?

Comment: java is pass by value. `a` is resolved, and the _value_ that it resolves to is pushed on the stack. A copy, effectively. No shuffling done - copying is done. It's no different from `System.out.println(a + b)`. Start running `javap` instead of asking SO questions if you find this stuff interesting (it has zero effect on your skills as java programmer, so if that was your aim, find something else to obsess over. But if you find this stuff interesting, good for you! `javap -c` (i.e. looking at bytecode) is the next step along the path to know more.

Comment: @chappie – *variables* are on the stack, all of them. Primitives and object references alike, as long as they are not part of an Object (although then they are usually referred to as *attributes* or *properties* and not as *variables*). More precise, the values of that variables are on the stack, and these values are … primitives or references!

Comment: One more question. Is the memory for each object (on the heap) contiguous like an array? ie Car class has make, model, price. Is make, model, and price contiguous memory?

Comment: Yes, all field data for _a single object_ is contiguous, but, remember that the thing stored to represent an object is merely a pointer. The actual objects they are pointing at need not be contiguous.

Answer (score -1):

Just step back a bit …

An object variable stores the reference to (the "address" of) an object. Such an object address is – as you might expect – a (numerical) value.

If a variable for a primitive would be the address of that value, what would be the difference between objects and primitives (and why would Java need that `Integer` class when it has already `ìnt`?)

So, no, a primitive variable directly holds the value for the primitive.

But of course that value has an address, only that this address is not accessible by Java code.

Comment: "...what would be the difference between objects and primitives" That's why I asked the question b/c the same question came to mind.