# How to print the size of a primitive data type in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   int x = 10;
   byte y = 125;
   float z = 2.5f;
   long ln = 50;
   // How can I know the size of this variables ?
   // it there any way to print the size of this primitive types ?
}
}
```

How can I know the size (byte) that is allocated for this data type in Java ?

Comment: I removed all the unrelated tags. Please don't tag spam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java primitive type variable storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67477260/java-primitive-type-variable-storage)

Comment: The "size" of primitives is defined in chapter [Primitive Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3) of the Java Virtual Machine Specification.

Comment: Given there size is fixed by specification, there is generally no good reason to have to query that in a program at runtime. Why do you even need to know this?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `SIZE` variable of the respective data type. It gives the size of the respective type in bits. If you need the values in bytes, you  can divide the values by 8.

```
System.out.println(Integer.SIZE); //32 bits
System.out.println(Byte.SIZE); //8 bits
System.out.println(Float.SIZE); //32 bits
System.out.println(Long.SIZE); // 64 bits
```

Edit: As pointed out by @Jorn there is also BYTES which gives the size in bytes. For example, for integer type,

```
System.out.println(Integer.BYTES); // 4 bytes
```

Comment: There's also `BYTES` for the size in bytes

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Jorn. Included it in the answer.